# (Re-)tokenize entities in a dataframe without losing the associated label

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, nlp

**Context**

I'm looking for a way to tokenize entities (in a CONLL) from a dataframe by following the rule: ["d'Angers"] => ["d '", "Angers"] / ["l'impératrice" ] => ["l'", "impératrice"] (split entities on apostrophes).

**Code**

My initial dataframe looks like this (correponding to CONLL file) :

```
 Sentence  Mention  Tag
9   3   Vincennes   B-LOCATION
10  3   .   O
12  4   Confirmation    O
13  4   des O
14  4   privilèges  O
15  4   de  O
16  4   la  O
17  4   ville   O
18  4   d'Aire  O
19  4   1   O
20  4   ,   O
21  4   au  O
22  4   bailliage   B-ORGANISATION
23  4   d'Amiens    I-ORGANISATION
```

First create a Retokenization class :

```py
class Retokenization:
    def __init__(self, mention) -> None:
        self.mention = mention
        self.tokens = self.split_off_apostrophes()
    
    def split_off_apostrophes(self):
        if "'" in self.mention and len(self.mention) > 1:
            if not re.search(r"[\-]", str(self.mention)) and not re.search(r"[\w]{2,}['][\w]+", str(self.mention)):
                inter = re.split(r"(\w')", self.mention)
                tokens = [tok for tok in inter if tok != '']
                return tokens
            else:
                return self.mention.split()
        else:
            return self.mention.split()
```

then apply this retokenize class to dataframe :

```py
mentions = df['Mention'].apply(lambda mention : Retokenization(mention).tokens).fillna(value='_')
```

OUT :

```
9           [Vincennes]
10                  [.]
12       [Confirmation]
13                [des]
14         [privilèges]
15                 [de]
16                 [la]
17              [ville]
18           [d', Aire]
19                  [1]
20                  [,]
21                 [au]
22          [bailliage]
23         [d', Amiens]
```

Then I recreate the dataframe with my tokenized mentions and the associated labels :

```py
from itertools import chain

df_retokenized = pd.DataFrame({
    
    'Sentence' : df['Sentence'].values.repeat(mentions.str.len()),
    'Mention' : list(chain.from_iterable(mentions.tolist())),
    'Tag' : df['Tag'].values.repeat(mentions.str.len())

    })
```

and I add a boolean mask for some missing labels during recreate dataframe :

```py
m1 = df['Tag'].eq('O')
m2 = m1 & df['Tag'].shift(-1).str.startswith('I-')
add_tag = df['Tag'].shift(-1).str.replace(r"\w[-](\w+)", r"\1", regex=True)

df['Tag'] = np.select([m2], ['B-' + add_tag], df['Tag'])
```

OUT :

```
Mention Tag
JJ O
/ O
/ O
226 O
/ O
A O

465 O

Vincennes B-LOCATION
. O

Confirmation O
des O
privilèges O
de O
la O
ville O
d' O
Aire O
1 O
, O
au O
bailliage B-ORGANISATION
d' I-ORGANISATION
Amiens I-ORGANISATION
```

**Problem**

The code works but not fully operational. In fact, when I look further in the output file I notice that some retokenized entities have lost their Tag (IOB) for example:

Example # 1

Before :

```
Projet O
de O
" O
tour O
de O
l'impératrice B-TITLE
Eugénie B-PERSON
```

After :

```
Projet O
de O
" O
tour O
de O
l' O
impératrice 
Eugénie B-PERSON
```

Expected output :

```
Projet O
de O
" O
tour O
de O
l' O
impératrice B-TITLE
Eugénie B-PERSON
```

Example #2

Before :

```
à O
l'ONU B-ORGANISATION
, O
durée O
```

After :

```
à O
l' O
ONU O
, O
durée O
```

Expected output :

```
à O
l' O
ONU B-ORGANISATION
, O
durée O
```

I have other examples (but I don't want to overload the question)

**Question**

*Is there a way to apply my (re-)tokenization to the dataframe without losing NER tags on re-tokenized entities ?*

Excuse me for the length (I have not found other way to summarize correctly), if anyone has any leads, thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot here, so I'm not sure I'm understanding it all, but I think the approach can be simplified by using `apply` on the entire row and generating your new row data at the time of splitting. That way you keep the row integrity as you go and can remake your DataFrame at the very end without any fear that it fails to align. Take a look at my sample code. You should be able to apply any additional rules in the one `retokenize` function:

```
import pandas as pd
mydict = {'sentence':[3,3,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4], 
          'mention':['Vincennes', '.', 'Confirmation', 'des', 'privilèges', 'de', 'la', 'ville', 'd\'Aire', '1', ',','au','bailliage','d\'Amiens'], 
          'tag':['B-LOCATION', '0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','B-ORGANISATION', 'I-ORGANISATION']}
df = pd.DataFrame(mydict)

# function to recreate rows on the fly
def retokenize(row):
    if len(row['mention']) > 1:
        tokens = row['mention'].split("'")
        tokens_new = []
        # there's probably a more elegant way to do this part
        for i in range(0, len(tokens)-1):
            tokens_new.append(tokens[i] + "'")
        tokens_new.append(tokens[-1])
        output = []
        for i in tokens_new:
            if "'" in i:
                new_row = [row['sentence'], i, '0']
            else:
                new_row = [row['sentence'], i, row['tag']]
            output.append(new_row)
        return output
    else:
        return [[row['sentence'], row['mention'], row['tag']]]

# result will be a list of lists, each len(1) if no split ocurred or len(>1) if a split did occur
result = list(df.apply(retokenize, axis=1))
# now flatten so each row is an item in the parent list
result_flat = [e for i in result for e in i]
# and make new df 
new_df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(result_flat, columns=['sentence', 'mention', 'tag'])
new_df
sentence    mention     tag
0   3   Vincennes   B-LOCATION
1   3   .   0
2   4   Confirmation    0
3   4   des     0
4   4   privilèges  0
5   4   de  0
6   4   la  0
7   4   ville   0
8   4   d'  0
9   4   Aire    0
10  4   1   0
11  4   ,   0
12  4   au  0
13  4   bailliage   B-ORGANISATION
14  4   d'  0
15  4   Amiens  I-ORGANISATION
```